# Counter is not decremented in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Basically this game is a brick breaker in which I will be giving a quick basic background about it. The game will spawn 10 bricks at random locations, and if the all hits the brick 
once, the brick is destroyed. If all 10 bricks are destroyed then the user will be taken to the other scene (gamewon).

My main problem is that when I destroy all the bricks, I am not being redirected to the scene. However if I set the numberOfBricks to 1, it will work.. I can't really understand what's happening.

Thanks alot guys!
-HurpaDurpa

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BrickScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public int position_x = 0;
    public int position_y = 0;

    public GameObject Brick;
    public int brickDamage = 0;
    public int numberOfBricks = 10;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        Brick = GameObject.Find ("Brick");
        position_x = Random.Range (-6, 6);
        position_y = Random.Range(-1, 4);

        transform.position = new Vector3 (position_x, position_y, transform.position.z);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (brickDamage == 1) { //destroy brick on 1 hit

            numberOfBricks--;
            Object.Destroy (gameObject); //so it will destroy the hit object
                }

        if (numberOfBricks == 0) {
                        Application.LoadLevel (1);
                        numberOfBricks = 10;//Variable resetted
                }

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        brickDamage++;
    }

}
```

Comment: you should use the tag unity3d not unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you seem to have attached the script above to each brick.

So what is really happening is when any one of your bricks get hit, the **numberOfBricks** reduces by 1, resulting the value going to 9. This will happen to each brick.

Rather, what you need to do is to keep this **numberOfBricks** counter in another script. In the OnCollisionEnter portion of your code, you should reduce the **numberOfBricks** variable in the other script by 1.

Do that and you'll see the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, it worked! What I did was to create a public static variable, and then i reduced the couter from the bricksScript. Thanks again mate take care